# Get Date Limitation SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, limit

So what I am trying to do is get the total funded contracts of each month and then the YEAR TO DATE at the end of the 12th month. So I had already gone and have done that successfully.

The problem is I want the dates to be specific. What I mean by dates to be specific is I want all of the contracts only for 2014 year period. Also I want the user to see the past months meaning lets say We are in June, So the user can see any other month up until January. That is because those months have passed and are within the year 2014. Lets say we go to JULY we are not suppose to see July because we are still in June. But once we are in August we will be able to see July's funded contracts. So, I do NOT want the current month. But only up to the last day of the previous month.

This is my where Claus. I am a bit confused of how I entered my Where Claus for Date functions. 
I am using Report builder so can someone help me with the expression or Query. Its running fine just not showing the limitation of with in present month. What I mean is it will show the future months which I don't want it too. I am using Report Builder. I have 3 parameters. @BeginDate,@EndDate, And @program which is a drop down that lets the user pick which company they want. 
Thank you any help will be appreciated

```
FROM tdealer a JOIN tContact b ON a.contact_id = b.contact_id 
JOIN tContract c ON a.dealer_id = c.dealer_id 
JOIN tCompany d ON c.company_id = d.company_id
WHERE YEAR(c.Funded_date) = @Year 
  AND c.Funded_date >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-4, 0) 
  AND c.Funded_date < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, 0) 
  and c.program_id = @program 
  And c.funded_date Between @Begin_Date And @End_Date 
  AND @Begin_Date < GETDATE() AND @End_Date < GETDATE()
GROUP BY
  d.name,
  a.dealer_code,
  b.last_name,
  b.city,
  b.state,
  b.phone
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

WHERE year(c.Funded_date) = @year and month(c.funded_date) <= month(getdate())

this will only return rows where funded_date in the year of @year and in the current month or earlier.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Unfortunately it didn't go as planned in my query but thanks for the suggestion it made me think of other ways.